# Downloading .json file from Json Url in Playframework

Tags: javascript, java, html, playframework-2.5

Sorry but I am new in Playframwork

wanted download the data from Db as json file. I am able to convert DB data and display on browser but not able to download as json file.

```
public Result userListToJson() {
    List<User> userList = User.find.all();
    return ok(Json.toJson(userList))
}
```

Comment: You mean "json", not "jason", right?

Comment: what is a Jason/JSON URL anyway? Something like json://my.cool.json/doyoudigit

Comment: Can you add some more details, like any error messages, HTTP codes, etc, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Content-Disposition` header, so your code will be

```
public Result userListToJson() {
    List<User> userList = User.find.all();
    return ok(Json.toJson(userList)).withHeaders("Content-Disposition" -> "attachment; filename=users.json")
}
```